# Организация антифрод систем

Tags: веб-программирование

Каким образом антифрод системы используют собранные отпечатки браузера для отслеживания, если часть из них может быть подменена? Например сайт собирает данные о 50 различных параметрах браузера (агент, ОС, отпечатки шрифтов, отпечатки WebGL и т.д.), каждый раз 40 из них подменяются, а 10 остаются прежними. Может ли система сделать вывод, что это один и тот же пользователь использующий подмену параметров? Если из всех параметров рассчитывается один результат (хэш), то достаточно небольших изменений, чтобы агент был новым для системы. Логичнее объединять параметры в группы и сравнивать результаты, верно?

На сколько хорошо или плохо, если отпечатки в следствие подмены получаются уникальными и ни у каких других агентов не встречаются? Имеет ли смысл отслеживать время, требуемое для снятия определённого отпечатка браузера, чтобы определить подмену (процесс может занимать больше времени чем обычно).